# Have 2 Routers on the same ADSL2 Internet Connection

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I currently have a Router that is ADSL2 & VPN capable. It currently allows me to work from home and connect to work servers securely. I have used `traceroute www.google.com` in CMD to determine that all web requests/traffic goes through the VPN server rather than just the requests to access files on the VPN server.

I don't feel comfortable having all my traffic now go through work servers(the VPN) so I would like to avoid this. I know I have 2 solutions:

- Use Split Tunelling on the router where only requests to files on the VPN server will go through the VPN server, all other traffic is not through the VPN. I have heard that this can compromise the whole network as one node is currently 'unsecured' and can affect/compromise the whole network. Is this true?
- Add a second Router that doesn't connect through the VPN. When I finish work I disconnect from the VPN Routers wireless connection and connect through the second routers wireless connection.

I would like to take solution 2 because I wont be compromising the whole network but I have some questions:

- Is this something you would recommend?
- Is it dangerous? Is it just as compromising as solution 1?
- In Australia we use physical Phone Splitters for our internet physical connection. One side of the splitter connects to a phone line port on the wall. The other side has 2 ports, one for the phone line connection and one for the router/adsl connection. If I have 2 routers I'll need a splitter that has more than 2 ports so I can connect the 2nd router to the internet. Are there Phone Splitters with more than 2 ports and do ISP's allow me to do this?

Comment: *"I currently have a Router that is ADSL2..."*  -- You seem to be using the term "router" and "modem+router" interchangeably.  An ADSL line can only be connected to one ADSL modem (at your end).  You cannot connect two modems to one ADSL line by splitting or any other method.  Your phone splitter is not unique to Australia.

Comment: Are you sure your router is what's connecting to the VPN? Typically you would connect to the VPN via software on your computer. So you just disconnect from the VPN on your computer rather than connecting to a different router.

Answer (score 0):

- I would not recommend option 2. It will work, but I think your concerns about option 1 are way overblown.  Specifically I believe your belief that "one end is not secured" is incorrect (to practical intents.   IE to any degree it may be insecure, an attacker can "call home" regardless of how traffic is routed if they compromise your system)

Option 2 is not dangerous.

You can't use 2 ADSL routers on 1 line simultaneously.   Again, I think its a mistake, but if you really want to do it, I'd recommend the following connection, assuming your VPN configuration can handle the NAT issues)

```
Connection type 1 (VPN Enabled):
Internet ------- ADSL ROUTER (no VPN) ---- New Router (with VPN) ---- PC

Connection type 2 (No VPN):
Internet ------- ADSL ROUTER (no VPN) ---- PC
```